# How to pull apart a querystring in C# when # provided instead of?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, identityserver3

I use .NET 4.7, MVC5, C#

I am receiving a querystring from 3rd party endpoint which has a # in it instead of a ? ie:

```
endpoint#code=123456&parm2=123....
```

instead of:

```
endpoint?code=123456&parm2=123....
```

My usual code of:

```
string[] codes = Request.Params.GetValues("code")
```

or

```
string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
```

will not deal with this. Keeps returning null. I am unable to get 3rd party to change this, apparently it is part of the oauth2 spec, something called a "hash fragment".

Is it possible to get the full returned url and pulled the relevant bit out via string handling routines?

While I cannot see the full URL in the debugger, if I let the endpoint complete, I see the full querystring with the # in it with the URL box of the browser. Wish I could get this in code to splice.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The # is an anchor symbol, and I'm pretty sure it's a browser side thing, used to locate a position on the page once it's loaded, and not sent in the request, which is why you can't see it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Definitely being returned by 3rd party's server, here is a link about it: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2710

Comment: The `#` is not part of the querystring. That's a url. The querystring starts after  a `?`. That URL is technically invalid

Comment: Have you tried the [solution specified in that git hub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2710#issuecomment-197004874) issue? *You need to add response_mode=query as a param, as per the spec if you want the results via query string (as opposed to the default of hash fragment).*

Comment: I will try it, but it was tried by Brock Allen in the forum, to no avail. But I will try it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment (everything after the `#` sign) is not send to the server according to [RFC 2396, section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4):

> However, "the URI" that results from such a
> reference includes only the absolute URI after the fragment
> identifier (if any) is removed and after any relative URI is resolved
> to its absolute form.

There is no way to retrieve it server side.

Comment: Ah, so you are saying that a redirect to say "localhost/endpoint#code=1234" would get the browser to call "endpoint", but with no parameters?

Comment: Yes, and on return, the browser (or software) adds the fragment to the response URL before rendering.

Comment: Is there any way of replacing this # with a ?, client side, say using Javascript, then forwarding to the server?

Comment: Yeah, you could do something like that with Javascript indeed. I would try as much as possible to alter the source (or get it altered).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will investigate the JS route. I will struggle to get the 3rd party to change this.